# Negative top on div and overlapping images

Tags: image, firefox

I'll be short.
http://www.tuttoinunafesta.info
Click on the second button of the top menu ("Feste per bambini") and look at the links that appear on the orange stripe.

In IE10 and Chrome they are vertically in the center of the stripe as they should be, because the images are 42px (the same div of the container div).
In Firefox they are some px below where they should be.

Why?

The container div of the menu-top buttons is overlapped by the container div of the colored stripe (in this case the orange one).
The bottom div has the following properties:
`{position:relative; top:-2px;}.`

It seems that Firefox can't overlap the images of the links over the images of the buttons even if the two divs are overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used a css reset? Browsers add padding and margins by default, but the problem is, they're all different. A simple css reset can be done with this code:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

There are more in-depth ones available on the web -  this is one of the most commonly used ones - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/.

Comment: Yes, as you can see analyzing any element with the Firefox tool I've applied that css rule. Unfortunately it doesn't seems to be the problem.